# How can I get MacPorts to create symlinks to MySQL Server?

Tags: mac-osx

I have installed `mysql55-server` using MacPorts 2.3.1 on a Mac Mini server being used within a commercial intranet environment. The installation ran smoothly (no errors or warnings) but the symlinks to the binaries (which are in `/opt/local/lib/mysql55/bin`) have not been placed in `/opt/local/bin`, which normally happens when installing using MacPorts.

I can manually replace the symlinks but I know this is not the right thing to do. How do I get MacPorts to create the symlinks?

Comment: This question has been reworded to fit the rules. Please consider re-opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself.

I had forgotten to run this command:

```
port select mysql mysql55
```

This relatively simple problem was deceptively hard to solve, so I hope this information proves helpful to others.